# Python SQLALCHEMY ERROR WHEN TRYING TO SAVE DF TO SQL DB

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am very new to programming. I have connected to an SQL table using in Python using `SQLALCHEMY`.
I have put the table into a dataframe and edited it, when trying to save the df to sql using the following code:

```py
DF.to_sql('DF_TABLE', Engine, index=False)
```

I receive the error below:

```
ReadOnlySqlTransaction: cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction
```

I also see "internal error". Please could somebody advice me on how to resolve this.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please post a [mre].

Comment: Google your error message. This is apparently a Postgres error, and happens when the DB is in read-only mode. This can happen if you try to perform modifications when connected to a replica, or it's in recovery mode, etc.